# Change Currency Format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, currency

I Have a field that should consist a currency, which is according to my Region is Indonesia which is IDR or Rp.
and i build it with `string.format` like this :

```
 Dim price As Single = Single.Parse(Convert.ToSingle(lblAmountGV.Text))
 lblAmount.Text = String.Format("{0,C}", price)
```

but it give me a dollar sign. and i Change the code :

```
 lblAmount.Text = String.Format("Rp{0}", price)
```

but i didn't get the `dot (.)` and `Comma(,)` . so I change the code again by using `FormatCurrency` :

```
 lblAmount.Text = FormatCurrency(lblAmountGV.Text, , , TriState.True, TriState.True)
```

but it still give me a Dollar sign, later i found how to change the `CultureInfo` :

by imports :

```
Imports System.Globalization
```

and on my code :

```
 Dim culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(" id-ID")
    Dim format = DirectCast(culture.NumberFormat.Clone(), NumberFormatInfo)
    format.CurrencySymbol = "Rp."
    var number = Decimal.Parse(lblAmountGV.Text, NumberStyles.Currency, format);

lblAmount.Text = number
```

but it still give me an `$` sign, how to change the `$` programatically?

Comment: When dealing with money, don't use the "Single" type, even if it seems large enough. Use the Decimal type. Always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple issues with what you posted -

this line is incorrect

```
String.Format("{0,C}", price)
```

You need to use a colon to add additional formatting arguments. If you want to format currency with decimal places than you also need to indicate the number of decimal digits. It should be something like this

```
String.Format("{0:C2}", price)
```

And this line has an extra space that causes it to fail with a `CultureNotFoundException`

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(" id-ID")
```

Should be

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("id-ID")
```

This code worked for me:

```
Dim culture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("id-ID")
Dim price As Double = 10.05

Dim result As String = String.Format(culture, "{0:C2}", price)
```

You can see it in action [here](http://ideone.com/SKZWOV)

If you are familiar with `LINQPad`, you can paste the following into LINQPad and see the proper formatting without the dollar sign -

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("id-ID"), "{0:C2}", 10.05).Dump()
```